# JSON response not a plain object

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, django

This is coming from a request to get all objects of a Django apps, it is not getting a plain object, as the print says it is just a string

Javascript :

```
  $.getJSON("/cadastro/getAllPessoas/", function(data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(typeof(data));
    console.log($.isPlainObject(data));
    //Raises error on isArrayLike():
    $.each(data,function(){
      arrayValues.push([this["pk"],this["fields"]["nome"]]);
    })
  });
```

Console output :

```
[{"model": "cadastroapp.djangotestpessoa", "pk": 1, "fields": {"nome": "Gabriel"}}] 
string
false
```

views.py :

```
from django.core import serializers
def getAllPessoas(request):
    data = serializers.serialize('json', Pessoa.objects.all(), fields=('objectid','nome'))
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Comment: have you tried to parse you json-string with `$.parseJSON()` ?

Comment: Yes i know that works, but I want to avoid an extra step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're serializing twice in the Django view, because both `serializers.serialize` and JsonResponse convert to JSON. Don't do that; just return a normal response with the serialized value.

```
return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: I added the serializer because JsonResponse said query sets can't be serialized

Comment: Yes. So don't use JsonResponse.